# Abstract class values not registering in 'extended' class

Tags: java, abstract-class

I wrote Java code using abstraction to calculate federal and state income tax from a salary.

The code is below.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

abstract class USA_Tax{
    protected final double income_tax = 0.15;
    protected double pre_tax_amount;
    protected double tax_to_fed;

    public void federal_tax(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Enter pre-tax income: ");
        double pre_tax_amount = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println ("Money owned to federal government: ");
        tax_to_fed = (double)(pre_tax_amount*0.15);
        System.out.println (tax_to_fed);
    input.close();
    }
}

class California_Tax extends USA_Tax{
    protected final double ca_income_tax = 0.10;
    protected double after_california_tax;
    protected double total_money_left;
    public void ca_tax(){
        after_california_tax = (double)(pre_tax_amount * ca_income_tax);
        System.out.println("Money owned to CA government: " + after_california_tax);
        total_money_left = (pre_tax_amount) - (after_california_tax + tax_to_fed);
        System.out.println ("Total take home:" + total_money_left);
    }    
}

public class class_abstraction{
    public static void main (String[] args){

        California_Tax tax1 = new California_Tax();
        tax1.federal_tax();
        tax1.ca_tax();
    }
}
```

When I run the code, only values from the abstract class seem to pop up correctly. The values for the after_california_tax and total_money_left variables in the extended class show up as 0.0. Below is an example output.

```
Enter pre-tax income: 
100000
Money owned to federal government: 
15000.0
Money owned to CA government: 0.0
Total take home:-15000.0
```

I also tried to remove 'abstract' from the first class but nothing changed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where you have messed up, you have created a new local variable which was not required, use the instance variable instead which you have defined.

```
double pre_tax_amount = input.nextDouble();
```

Code after the change is done

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

abstract class USA_Tax{
    protected final double income_tax = 0.15;
    protected double pre_tax_amount;
    protected double tax_to_fed;

    public void federal_tax(){
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Enter pre-tax income: ");
        pre_tax_amount = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println ("Money owned to federal government: ");
        tax_to_fed = (double)(pre_tax_amount*0.15);
        System.out.println (tax_to_fed);
    input.close();
    }
}

class California_Tax extends USA_Tax{
    protected final double ca_income_tax = 0.10;
    protected double after_california_tax;
    protected double total_money_left;
    public void ca_tax(){
        after_california_tax = (double)(pre_tax_amount * ca_income_tax);
        System.out.println("Money owned to CA government: " + after_california_tax);
        total_money_left = (pre_tax_amount) - (after_california_tax + tax_to_fed);
        System.out.println ("Total take home:" + total_money_left);
    }    
}

public class test{
    public static void main (String[] args){

        California_Tax tax1 = new California_Tax();
        tax1.federal_tax();
        tax1.ca_tax();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While I think that the other answers solve your specific problem.  It doesn't really feel like you have a reasonable grasp on what an abstract class is used for.  In general an abstract class is a class that doesn't have all its behavior defined, and that behavior has to be defined by the implementors/programmers that decide to use that class.  In your example how to calculate different tax rates.

To use actual abstraction, we would need a parent class that has an actual abstract method.

```
public abstract class Tax {

    private double income;

    public Tax(double income) {
        this.income = income;
    }
    public void printCalculation() {

        System.out.println("Money owned to federal government: ");
        double tax_to_fed = income * getTaxAmount();
        System.out.println(tax_to_fed);
    }

    public abstract double getTaxAmount();
}
```

Then we have two implementing classes.

```
public class UsaTax extends Tax {
    public UsaTax(double income) {
        super(income);
    }

    @Override
    public double getTaxAmount() {
        return .15;
    }
}
```

```
public class CaliforniaTax extends Tax {

    public CaliforniaTax(double income) {
        super(income);
    }

    @Override
    public double getTaxAmount() {
        return .10;
    }
}
```

Finally we have our main class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TaxApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println ("Enter pre-tax income: ");
        double pre_tax_amount = input.nextDouble();
        UsaTax usaTax = new UsaTax(pre_tax_amount);
        usaTax.printCalculation();
        CaliforniaTax californiaTax = new CaliforniaTax(pre_tax_amount);
        californiaTax.printCalculation();

        // We could even create an anonymous inner class
        Tax texasTax = new Tax(pre_tax_amount) {
            @Override
            public double getTaxAmount() {
                return 0;
            }
        };
        texasTax.printCalculation();
        input.close();
    }
}
```

The output:

```
Enter pre-tax income: 
10000
Money owned to federal government: 
1500.0
Money owned to federal government: 
1000.0
Money owned to federal government: 
0.0

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Sidenote

I believe the reason you tried to create abstract classes in the first place was to use the Scanner in the parent class.  By breaking the Scanner behavior out of your Tax class we reduce that class' coupling to a user input method and allows us to write that class with only its behavior in mind instead of what it needs to do and how to handle user input properly.

Answer (score 0):

In `public void federal_tax()`, you redefine the variable `pre_tax_amount`:

`double pre_tax_amount = input.nextDouble();`

You are thus not using the member variable defined above.
You need to assign the value in the already declared variable:

`pre_tax_amount = input.nextDouble();`